# Define a new environment to combine tikzpicture and lstlisting

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I would like to define a new environment to combine the `tikzpicture` environment from package `pgf/tikz` and the `lstlisting` environment from package `listings`. The result would be to first produce the picture, then, include verbatim code afterwards. It would be similar to the examples in the PGF manual. Till Tantau uses an environment `codeexample`, but it is too complicated for me to comprehend, and I don't need other functionalities such as extracting keywords etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `showexpl` package. It uses `listings` "under the hood", but also compiles your code example for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{tikz}

% showexpl uses the listings package, so you need to check
% its documentation for that.
% Set up the basic parameters for showing the code
\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
    commentstyle=\itshape\ttfamily\small,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakautoindent=true,
    captionpos=t
}
% set up the parameters for the examples themselves
\lstset{explpreset={rframe={},xleftmargin=1em,columns=flexible,language={}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}[pos=b]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[left color=white, right color=red]
      (0,0) rectangle +(3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

Output of this document:

[image: Sample code and tikz image]

Comment: Thanks! It looks like exactly what I want. I will read the manual.

Answer (score 2):

More options

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{tikz}

%define layout to tikz codes.
\definecolor{hellgelb}{rgb}{1,1,0.8}
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colComments}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
    language={},%
    float=hbp,%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny, %
    identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier}, %
    keywordstyle=\color{colKeys}, %
    stringstyle=\color{colString}, %
    commentstyle=\color{colComments}, %
    columns=flexible, %
    tabsize=4, %
    frame=single, %
    rframe={},%
    extendedchars=true, %
    showspaces=false, %
    showstringspaces=false, %
    numbers=none, %
    numberstyle=\tiny, %
    breaklines=true, %
    backgroundcolor=\color{hellgelb}, %
    breakautoindent=true, %
    captionpos=b,%
    xleftmargin=0pt%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{LTXexample}[width=2cm]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade[ball color=yellow] (0,0) circle (1);
  \draw[->,blue] (0,0) -- (45:1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document} ​
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, it seems that xleftmargin or xrightmargin for verbatim no longer has any effect when used in LTXexample. (they still work in the lstlisting environment.)

Comment: After playing around with the test file from showexpl, I found that when numbers=none, xleftmargin does not have any effect on verbatim. It only works when numbers=left or right. probably a bug?

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done with [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package help. Like `showexpl` it's able to print some `LaTeX` code and show its result at the same time.

Next code defines a `tikzexample` environment which will show `TiKZ` code on the left and the figure on the right. Option `tikz lower` saves us from typing `\begin{tikzpicure}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`.

`listing side text` is used as default appearance (first example) which can be changed through the optional parameter as is shown in second example.

The code for the figure has been copied form `tcolorbox` documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{tikzexample}[1][]{tikz lower, 
           listing side text, fonttitle=\bfseries,
           bicolor, colback=blue!15!white, colbacklower=white,
           colframe=black, righthand width=3cm, #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzexample}[title=Example]
\path[fill=yellow,draw=yellow!75!red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\fill[red] (45:5mm) circle (1mm);
\fill[red] (135:5mm) circle (1mm);
\draw[line width=1mm,red] (215:5mm) arc (215:325:5mm);
\end{tikzexample}

\begin{tikzexample}[title=Example, listing outside text]
\path[fill=yellow,draw=yellow!75!red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\fill[red] (45:5mm) circle (1mm);
\fill[red] (135:5mm) circle (1mm);
\draw[line width=1mm,red] (215:5mm) arc (215:325:5mm);
\end{tikzexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]