# How to define a new environment with a fancy box (tikz) around sample source-code (listings)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, listings, environments, boxes

This is what I want to do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame 1}

    Some \structure{Python} code here:

    % I want to define a new "pythoncode" environment, so I can use it like this:
    \begin{pythoncode}[hello.py]
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    def main():
        print "Hello, World!"
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
    \end{pythoncode}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But I want to customize the source-code box beyond what `listings` package allow me. [Jan Hlavacek suggested me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/can-i-get-a-shadowbox-with-rounded-corners-using-listings-package) to use `tikz` package for that, and pointed me to [a few examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/).

Okay, that's great! Tikz gives me enough power and freedom for customization! All I need now is creating a new environment, so that I can use this environment just like in the code above.

However, I'm having trouble mixing `tikz` with `listings` inside a new environment. I've tried the following code, but it doesn't work (I get *Missing \endcsname inserted.*):

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}

\tikzstyle{sourcecodebox} = [
    draw=blue, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners,
    inner sep=10pt
]
\tikzstyle{sourcecodetitle} = [
    fill=black, text=white,
    rectangle, rounded corners
]
\NewEnviron{pythoncode}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[sourcecodebox](box){
        \begin{lstlisting}[
            language=Python,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
            escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
            %numbers=left,
            breaklines=true,
            breakatwhitespace=true,
            showspaces=false,
            showstringspaces=false,
            frame=shadowbox,
            frameround=rrrt,
            rulecolor=\color{black},
            rulesepcolor=\color{gray}
        ]
        \BODY
        \end{lstlisting}
    };
    \node[sourcecodetitle] at (box.north west) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Related questions:

- [Defining a new environment whose contents go in a TikZ node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5639/defining-a-new-environment-whose-contents-go-in-a-tikz-node) - It suggests using the `environ` package.
- [define a new environment to combine tikzpicture and lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8993/define-a-new-environment-to-combine-tikzpicture-and-lstlisting) - The question title looks similar, but in fact the question is very different. That question is solved using `showexpl` package.

Comment: Not really answering your question, but how about actually having a `hello.py` file with the code, and then use `\lstinputlisting{hello.py}`. You avoid the problem altogether because you don't need to define an environment anymore.

Comment: @Denilson Use the listings environment command to create the environment `\lstnewenvironment`

Comment: @Juan: No, I don't want to put an external file because I'm going to use several snippets of source code throughout several slides, so it's a lot better to have them inline with the slide text. Also, sometimes I'll want to highlight some lines from the source code, and thus I need the source inline, mixed with TeX. See this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code

Comment: @Yiannis: Before writing the code from my question, I've tried using `\lstnewenvironment`, but I failed completely, because I needed to open `\begin{tikzpicture}` inside the first pair of braces and then close it inside another set of braces. Since that is not possible, another question from this site suggested using the `environ` package. Anyway, if you have a working solution, please share with us!

Comment: @Denilson, this question looks like a duplicate of your [earlier question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/can-i-get-a-shadowbox-with-rounded-corners-using-listings-package). In order to avoid duplicating efforts trying to answer your question, perhaps you would like to delete this question and update the earlier one with any new information, the things you have tried and why they didn't work?

Comment: I thought it was a different enough question. The earlier one asks about using just `listings` pacakge, while this one asks about integrating `listings` with `tikz`. I think that a simple "No, you can't do it with just `listings` package" is an acceptable answer for the earlier one. Actually, the previous question gave me the idea about asking this question.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `\NewEnviron` does not support verbatim. The documentation should point that out. As already commented the `\lstnewenvironment` must be used for this. Alternatively place the verbatim files into external files which are then read using `\listinputlisting`.

Find below my solution which stores the resulting listings first into a box which is then used inside the TikZ node. IMHO you should not mix the listings
`frame` argument with additional frames from TikZ. You should produce all framing using TikZ (not to be confused with beamers `\frame` macro/environment).
Beamer provides some nice framed boxes as well!

I had to add the `linewidth` argument and a `\makebox`, otherwise the listings frame is to wide. You might want to adjust that.

Best Regards,
Martin

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{sourcecodebox} = [
    draw=blue, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners,
    inner sep=10pt
]
\tikzstyle{sourcecodetitle} = [
    fill=black, text=white,
    rectangle, rounded corners
]

\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{pythoncode}[1][]{%
    \def\pythoncodetitle{#1}%
    \lstset{%
        language=Python,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
        escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
        %numbers=left,
        breaklines=true,
        breakatwhitespace=true,
        showspaces=false,
        showstringspaces=false,
        frame=shadowbox,
        frameround=rrrt,
        linewidth=.75\linewidth,
        rulecolor=\color{black},
        rulesepcolor=\color{gray}
    }%
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox\bgroup\color@setgroup
}%
{%
    \color@endgroup\egroup
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[sourcecodebox] (box)
            % Makebox is needed to take the frame added by listings into account
            {\makebox[.75\linewidth][l]{\box\@tempboxa}};
        \node[sourcecodetitle] at (box.north west) {\pythoncodetitle};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame 1}

    Some \structure{Python} code here:
    \begin{pythoncode}[hello.py]
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    def main():
        print "Hello, World!"
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
    \end{pythoncode}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

`tcblisting` environments from [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package are a good tool to define fancy boxes around source code. `tcolorbox` provides the surrounding box and it works with `listings` and `minted` packages to format source code.

Next it's just an example which shows some customization options:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{pythoncode}[2][]{%
    enhanced, title=#2, colframe=blue!50!black, 
    colback=blue!10!white, sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\ttfamily, coltitle=white,
    attach boxed title to top left = {yshift=-.5mm} ,
    boxed title style={sharp corners, size=small, colback=blue!75!black},
    listing only,listing options={language=python},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame 1}

    Some \structure{Python} code here:

    % I want to define a new "pythoncode" environment, so I can use it like this:
    \begin{pythoncode}{hello.py}
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    def main():
        print "Hello, World!"
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
    \end{pythoncode}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]